# Lining up floating elements on line wrap

Tags: html, css, css-float, responsive-design

I have the following setup : http://jsfiddle.net/GdDhT/

When the line of floating divs wraps, the first one on the second line is not where I want it to be (because of the size of the div above it)

I cannot adding a clearing div like this :

because when the screen is larger, #floating-div-1, 2 and 3 will appear next to each other in a single line. I cannot add a clear on a specific div for the same reason. Same problem with the :nth-child css rules.

This is part of a responsive design, so I cannot rely on exact width calculations as the size on the divs varies.

Depending on screen size, the result I want to achieve would be : [image]

or

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap each of your div's in a div wrapper with min-height, then they'll break like you want.  But that also means your wrappers are a fixed height.  This type of a solution would work well with jQuery which could grab the height of the first content div and set the rest of the wrapper divs to it's height.

I've updated the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GdDhT/1/), the box-shadow is just to show the wrapping min-height.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to avoid fixed height or jQuery to set column height but I think it's pretty much unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

nth child could possibly help you - make the first div on every line clear it's left:

```
#parent-div div:nth-child(2n-1){
    clear: left;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k5DXN/1/

Comment: I edited my question with more details. This solution doesn't work for me because a line doesn't always have 2 divs in it. Depending on the size of parent-div, it might contain 1 floating-div or 3 floating-div. The markup cannot look like this. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Edited my solution. I couldn't understand why nth-child is not good. Am i missing anything?

Comment: OK, I've edited my question with your fiddle (thanks for that btw) and hopefully it's more clear now.

Comment: Thanks. Went with individual wrappers in the end. Far from elegant, but an acceptable solution in my case (didn't really want to use js for that)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand your different use cases but adding:

```
clear:left
```

to `#floating-div-3` should bump it down under `#floating-div-1`.

Comment: I've edited my question with a bit more details. I cannot clear floating-div-3 because the size of parent-div changes depending on screen size (and so floating-div-3 will not always be the div that needs to be cleared)

Comment: I recently had this same issue and ended up setting heights on my divs so they would line up. I've also had reasonable, though not total, success with [setting equal column heights via jquery](http://www.jainaewen.com/files/javascript/jquery/equal-height-columns.html)  But I'm not aware of a pure CSS way to solve this. Strictly speaking, it's doing what it is supposed to.